# User registration email translation

Tags: 8

I am working on an English/Arabic website, the user can switch between the two languages using the language switch block, I wanted to translate the email sent to the user after registration. So after some digging, I figured out I could do this using the account setting (translate tab), I added the Arabic translation of the email; then, after testing, I found out that the registration email is still sent in English.

Shouldn't a user registered in the Arabic language get an Arabic registration email?

I also found out that the user's preferred language is English, even after registering in the Arabic language.

These are my language detection settings.

> [image]
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have configured the translations correctly. 
On the account settings page you will be able to see the **Translate Settings** tab here `/admin/config/people/accounts`

[image]
After clicking on the link here you will find the enabled languages with options in front of them

[image]

Click on edit and then you will be able to see all the Account settings to be translated including mail where you can `write / modify` the text in mail like in following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I already did those steps, still not working